# error: Value of type variable "AnyStr" of "urljoin" cannot be "Optional[str]" in mypy

Tags: python, urllib, mypy, python-3.8, static-typing

I have a statement like this:

```py
import os
from urllib.parse import urljoin

ES_SEARCH_URL = urljoin(base=os.getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_URL"), url="index/_search")
```

I have tried with giving many types for `ES_SEARCH_URL`, but it always gives the following error whenever I run mypy.

```
error: Value of type variable "AnyStr" of "urljoin" cannot be "Optional[str]"
```

Options I have tried so far:

```
from typing import Optional, AnyStr, Union
ES_SEARCH_URL: Union[str, None] = urljoin(base=os.getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_URL"), url="index/_search")
ES_SEARCH_URL: Optional[str] = urljoin(base=os.getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_URL"), url="index/_search")
ES_SEARCH_URL: Optional[AnyStr] = urljoin(base=os.getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_URL"), url="index/_search")
```

How to resolve this error? Please help.
Python version: *Python 3.8*

Comment: What should happen if there is no `ELASTICSEARCH_URL` environment variable? That's the case mypy is warning you about.

Comment: You can't fix this by changing the type declared for `ES_SEARCH_URL`, because `ES_SEARCH_URL` isn't the problem.

Comment: As it is there in the `urljoin` codebase, if the `base` is not there, `urljoin` will return the `url` value. As `url` is always `str`, in this case, how should I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `os.getenv` can return `None` mypy can't know if it's a string value or a `None`.

Try giving it a default:

```
os.getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_URL", default="http://some.url.example.com/")
```

or handle the `None` case:

```
base_url = os.getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_URL")
if base_url is None:
  # handle here
ES_SEARCH_URL = urljoin(base=base_url, url="index/_search")
```

Reference: [this github issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8012)